# Handling error responses as JSON doing http requests

Tags: json, http, go, error-handling, httpresponse

I have an exposed endpoint `http://localhost:8000/api/getCourses`. Upon receiving a request to this endpoint, it calls a method `getCourseDetails` as shown below.

```
response, err := getCourseDetails(courseId) // response is a struct with multiple parameters, err is a struct with only title and message parameters
if err != nil {
   return getErrorJSON(c,err) #This method sends an response with 409 or 422 as status code and an error struct in body
}

return c.JSON(http.statusOK, response) // c is echo.Context
```

When I tested this using postman, everything works fine, and I get the expected output. But what I actually have to do is to call this endpoint from a different program. And I am doing it as follows,

```
URL = http://localhost:8000/api/getCourses
body := make(map[string]string)
body[courseid] = "12345"

payload, _ = json.Marshall(body)
req, _ = http.NewRequest("POST",URL,bytes.NewBuffer(payload))
req.Header.Set("Context-Type","application/json",charset="UTF-8")

client = &http.Client{}

course = Course{} // Response will be of this type after unmarshalling

response, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR OCCURED")
}

defer response.Body.close()

res, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
err = json.Unmarshall(res, &course)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("ERROR: %+v",err)
}

fmt.Printf("COURSE DETAILS: %+v", course)
```

This works fine when a successful transaction is done, that is when the received status is 200. In such cases, err is nil and I am able to print the course struct. However, when the response has some different status code (409 or 422), this does not work. So How do I modify the code on client-side to receive error responses as well?

Comment: You can check for `response.StatusCode`

Comment: Can you elaborate? I mean, how do I do that? I am pretty new to golang.

Comment: `http.Response` object (`response` in your code) has fields StatusCode and Status. so you can add checks you want.

Comment: `#` is not a valid go syntax.

Comment: @mh-cbon Yeah, I know. I mostly code in python. So when I was adding comments in the code here, I typed # instead of //

Comment: @OlegButuzov So, but how will I get unmarshal error response? I need to be able to print the error struct if a bad response is received. And here, I am not even getting a non-nil error in such cases.

Comment: why do you need unmarshal anything if status code isn't one you looking for? `if` almost same in Python as in Go

Comment: The `error` return value tells you if it failed to make the request at all. That's not the case you're trying to account for; you're trying to account for a successful request, that received a response, where the response is the server saying there was some error. That means you want to examine the response - the status code and response body. This is not unique to Go, it's simply how HTTP works.

Answer (score 0):

Mate, just check the status code from the http response.

```golang
...

response, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR OCCURED")
}

statusCode := response.StatusCode

// evaluate the status code...

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the response statuscode.

```
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
   fmt.Printf("err: %s", err)
   return
}

if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
   fmt.Printf("expected 200, got %d", resp.StatusCode)
   return
}

// Continue with your logic
```

I think you may be assuming that Go throws an error if the response isn't in the 200 range - **it doesn't.** It returns your response anyway, and doesn't care what the statuscode is.

Comment: How do I capture and print the received error object?